# eliminar opciones especificas de un select

Tags: javascript

Tengo 1 select, quiero que cuando la pagina se cargue. se eliminen solo los option que apareccan en el array Es posible?

```
<select>
    <option value="1/12/2018">Diciembre-2018</option>
    <option value="1/11/2018">Noviembre-2018</option>
    <option value="1/10/2018">Octubre-2018</option>
    <option value="1/9/2018">Septiembre-2018</option>
    <option value="1/8/2018">Agosto-2018</option>
</select>
<script>
    var list = ["Noviembre-2018", "Septiembre-2018"];
    $('select option').filter(function () {
      return $.inArray(this.innerHTML, list) == -1
    }).remove();
</script>
```

lo que quiero que quede

```
<select>
    <option value="1/12/2018">Diciembre-2018</option>
    <option value="1/10/2018">Octubre-2018</option>
    <option value="1/8/2018">Agosto-2018</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ser honesto, no es recomendable usar el texto de un `<option>` para hacer este tipo de filtros, siempre es bueno usar el `value`, sin embargo, en caso de que tu value cambie el contenido que deseas extraer o comparar, te recomiendo usar [atributos de datos](https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/atributos-personalizados-en-html5-mas-datos-con-un-simple-data).

En mi caso usé un `array.forEach` para recorrer el array y compararlo con cada `<option>` del `<select>`.

```js
var fechas = ["Noviembre-2018", "Septiembre-2018"];

fechas.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item) {
  $("#fechas option").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) ==  item
  }).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fechas">
  <option value="1/12/2018">Diciembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/11/2018">Noviembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/10/2018">Octubre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/9/2018">Septiembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/8/2018">Agosto-2018</option>
</select>
```

Edit: A petición del usuario, hice también el script correspondiente usando el value, en este caso, se modificó el array principal para que coincidiera con la data a comprar en el value.

```js
var fechas = ["1/11/2018", "1/9/2018"];

fechas.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item) {
  $('#fechas option[value="'+item+'"]').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="fechas">
  <option value="1/12/2018">Diciembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/11/2018">Noviembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/10/2018">Octubre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/9/2018">Septiembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/8/2018">Agosto-2018</option>
</select>
```

Comment: y como lo seria con los value? ,muchas gracias ante todo

Comment: @Reimundo acabo de editar la respuesta con el script que me acabas de pedir.

Comment: Me permito señalar que tu código no está optimizado, al meter un bucle dentro de otro bucle sin ninguna necesidad, se está iterando `N1xN2`, donde `N1` es la cantidad de opciones que haya en el `select` y `N2` el tamaño de `list`. Para probarlo, puedes poner un `console.log` dentro de este bloque `$("#fechas option").filter(function(){  console.log(1);  `... y verás que el `1` se imprime 10 veces. Y mientras más grandes sean ambos, más iteraciones. No hace falta iterar sobre `list`, es un error de enfoque. Se puede iterar sobre las opciones verificando si están en `list`.

Comment: @BrayamValero  tratare de optimizar el código y muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código estaba casi bien, sólo que tenías que poner la condición en negativo:

```
    return !($.inArray(this.innerHTML, list) == -1);
```

Así quitaría los que están en el array.

```js
$(function() {

var list = ["Noviembre-2018", "Septiembre-2018"];
  $('select option').filter(function() { 
    return !($.inArray(this.innerHTML, list) == -1);
  }).remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1/12/2018">Diciembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/11/2018">Noviembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/10/2018">Octubre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/9/2018">Septiembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/8/2018">Agosto-2018</option>
</select>
```

Estoy de acuerdo con @BrayamValero en que es mejor usar el `value` para esto. Con ese dato, sería así:

```js
$(function() {

var list = ["1/11/2018", "1/9/2018"];
  $('select option').filter(function() { 
    return !($.inArray(this.value, list) == -1);
  }).remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1/12/2018">Diciembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/11/2018">Noviembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/10/2018">Octubre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/9/2018">Septiembre-2018</option>
  <option value="1/8/2018">Agosto-2018</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias te pasaste :)